# How can you count matches from a join action in CakePHP?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, join

I want to count to an extra field created, the matches from a join. Is this possible in CakePHP?
I have an example of my data that I curently have.

And how would a query look in mySQL for this type of result?

Table:goal

```
id | name 
-----------
1    Goal X
2    Goal Y
```

Table: tasks

```
id | name | goal_id
-------------------
1    task1  1
2    task2  1
3    task3  2
4    task4  2
5    task5  2
```

Result

```
id | name | matches
-------------------
1    goal1  2
2    goal2  3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL query :

```
SELECT goal.id, goal.name, Count( * ) AS matches
FROM goal
RIGHT JOIN task ON goal.id = task.goal_id
GROUP BY goal.id
```

CakePHP : [if you have model with name Goal and Task]

```
$options['fields'] = array(
                           'Goal.id', 
                           'Goal.name', 
                           'count(*) AS matches'
                   );
$options['joins'] = array(
                              array(
                                 'table' => 'tasks',
                                 'alias' => 'Task',
                                 'type' => 'Right',
                                 'conditions' => array(
                                    'Goal.id = Task.goal_id'
                                 )
                              ) 
                    );
$options['group'] = array('Goal.id');
                           
$result = $this->Goal->find('all', $options);
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql should be that:

```
Select goal.id,goal.name,Count(*) From goal RIGHT JOIN tasks on goal.id=tasks.goal_id Group by goal.id
```

CakePHP, can't tell you without testing...